# How do I make this regex stop at the first match?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm converting a lot of code from legacy to maintainable and I'm creating a list of regex we can use to do all the pages quickly and the same. My regex skills are that of a child running with a knife...its not great. I've looked up a lot of different ways to only find the first set but I can't seem to get it to work. Can anyone solve this specific problem for me?

Here is the regex search and replace I'm using.

**regex:** `(rs.*)\.Fields\[\"(\w+)\"\].Value`

**replace:** `$1.GetValue<object>("$2")`

### Works

**code to search:** `...rsProducts.Fields["Price"].Value...`

**result:** `rsProducts.GetValue<object>("Price")`

This, as I want it to, finds the rs (recordset) of something and changes the way that we extract the value to use an extension method.

### Does Not Work

**code to search:** `...rsProducts.Fields["Price"].Value + rsProducts.Fields["Price2"].Value...`

**result:** `rsProducts.Fields["Price"].Value + rsProducts.Fields["Price2"].Value`

**should be:** `rsProducts.GetValue<object>("Price") + rsProducts.GetValue<object>("Price2")`

In this case the search does match 2 distinct instances but instead it matches the entire line. Here's a pic from regexr.com.

// sorry I don't have the reputation to post the image as an image but heres the 
[Link to Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZ3jy.jpg)

Comment: Use lazy dot matching pattern - [`(rs.*?)\.Fields\[\"(\w+)\"\].Value`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28rs.*%3f%29%5c.Fields%5c%5b%5c%22%28%5cw%2b%29%5c%22%5c%5d.Value&i=...rsProducts.Fields%5b%22Price%22%5d.Value..%0d%0a...rsProducts.Fields%5b%22Price%22%5d.Value+%2b+rsProducts.Fields%5b%22Price2%22%5d.Value...&r=%241.GetValue%3cobject%3e%28%22%242%22%29).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not dealing handling the case for the `+` between the two.

```
(rs.*?)\.Fields\[\"(\w+)\"\].Value
```